# Spring Rest Doc - generate html without maven

Tags: spring-restdocs

I am using Spring Rest Doc and I am generating the HTML file of the documentation using the mvn:install.

Now I have been asked to generate this file without maven cause in our project we are not going to use it.

Is there any way to generate it without the maven install task?

Thank you

Comment: How are you going to build the project and run the tests if you're not going to use Maven?

Comment: I am using ant for building the project and cucumber for testing.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [Asciidoctor Ant task](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-ant) that can be used to generate HTML from Asciidoctor in an Ant build.